# Does $\hat \theta_n=\theta+O_p\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\bigg)$ imply that $p_{\hat \theta_n X}(x)=p_{\theta X}(x)+O_p\bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\bigg)$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, density-function, convergence

Let $X$ be a random variable. Let $\theta$ be a constant, and let $\hat \theta_n$ be a set of normally distributed random variables that converge in probability to $\theta$, that is, $\hat \theta_n \stackrel{p}{\to} \theta$.

Suppose that we also know the rate of convergence:
$$
\hat \theta_n = \theta + o_p\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg).
$$

Define $p_{\theta X}$ and $p_{\hat \theta_n X}$ to be the pdf's of $\theta X$ and $\hat \theta_n X$, respectively.

Thus, $p_{\theta X}$ is just the pdf of a constant times a random variable, whereas $p_{\hat \theta_n X}$ is the pdf of a product of random variables.

Does the rate of convergence carry over to the probability density evaluated at the point $x$, that is, can we say the following?
$$
p_{\hat \theta_n X}(x) = p_{\theta X}(x) + o_p\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg).
$$

Comment: I have voted to close my own post because I think it is more appropriate for mathoverflow.

Comment: in your context, would it make sense to assume $X$ and $\hat\theta_n$ are independent?

Comment: Yes it is fine to assume they are indepedent.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that $p_{\hat{\theta}_nX}(x)=p_{\theta X}(x(1+o_p(\frac{1}{n})/\theta))$ because you are affecting characteristics of distribution by shifting mean(and scaling variance),
$$p_{\hat{\theta}_nX}(x)=p_X(\hat\theta x)=p_X(x(\theta +o_p(1/n)))=p_X(\theta x(1 +o_p(1/n)/\theta))=p_{\theta X}(x(1+o_p(\frac{1}{n})/\theta))$$

moreover integrating $\int p_{\hat{\theta}_nX}(x)dx=1 \land \int p_{\theta_nX}(x)dx=1$ but considering your change in density:

$$p_{\hat{\theta}_nX}(x)>p_{\theta X}(x) => 1=\int p_{\theta_nX}(x)dx < \int p_{\hat\theta_nX}(x)dx =>\underline{\int p_{\hat\theta_nX}(x)dx > 1}$$ which is contradiction because density should integrate to $1$

Comment: How are you getting $p_{\hat \theta_n X}(x) > p_{\theta X}(x)$ for all $x$? I am very familiar with the regular $o$ asymptotic notation but I'm just getting used to this $o_p$ probability notation.

Comment: It would be great if you could show how you arrived at $p_{\hat{\theta}_nX}(x)=p_{\theta X}(x(1+o_p(\frac{1}{n})/\theta))$?

Comment: I don't know how you are saying $p_{\hat{\theta}_nX}(x)=p_X(\hat\theta_n x)$? The pdf $p_{\hat{\theta}_nX}$ has a product distribution so it can be expressed as shown in my earlier edit.